# How to redefine Section and Subsection in autoref names

Tags: sectioning, autoref

I want do redefine Section and Subsection in autoref names the same way

```
\renewcommand\chaptername{NewChapterName}
\renewcommand\chapterautorefname{NewChapterName}
```

do with Chapter names.

How i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understand what you want to do (there is no MWE in the question).

Assuming you are loading package `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \def\chaptername{NewChapterName}%
  \def\sectionname{NewSectionName}%
  \def\subsectionname{NewSubsectionName}%
}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \def\chapterautorefname{Auto-NewChapterName}%
  \def\sectionautorefname{Auto-NewSectionName}%
  \def\subsectionautorefname{Auto-NewSubsectionName}%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}\label{chap}
\section{Section Title}\label{sec}
\subsection{Names}\label{subsec}
\chaptername, \sectionname, \subsectionname
\subsection{Autorefnames}
\autoref{chap}, \autoref{sec}, \autoref{subsec}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

**Update**

If you are using an other language you have to replace »english« by the name of this language in `\captionsenglish` and `\extraenglish`, eg.

```latex
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\addto\captionsbrazil{...}
\addto\extrasbrazil{...}
```

Comment: Yes, you got the point. But I tried this, and it did not work.

Comment: @Marco My example as above? Or my code in your document? Note, there is no MWE in your question. So nobody knows what you really doing. Additionally nobody knows what »did not work« means.

Comment: Your example. But I solved it, I posted an answer. Thanks!

Comment: My example works for `english`. In your question `brazil` is not mentioned :( So nobody knows that this language should be used. And if you replace option `english` by option `brazil`, `\captionsenglish` by `\captionsbrazil` and `\extrasenglish` by `\extrasbrazil`, it still works ...

Comment: You are right. 
I will just comment my previous answer here and mark your answer as accepted.

"My solution: 

I solved it.

I had to change the default names of Babel package, in this case, the brazilian captions:

`\addto\captionsbrazil{
\renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Seção}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Seção}
\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Seção}
}`

So, the Chapter, Section and Subsection Autoref names were changed to "Seção" names."
Sorry for not paying more attention to your code, and for not mentioning that I used the Brazilian language.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I had to change the default names of Babel package, in this case, the brazilian captions:

```
\addto\captionsbrazil{
\renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Seção}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Seção}
\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{Seção}
}
```

So, the Chapter, Section and Subsection Autoref names were changed to "Seção" names.

Comment: In your question brazil is not mentioned :( So nobody knows that this language should be used. And if you replace option english by option brazil, \captionsenglish by \captionsbrazil and \extrasenglish by \extrasbrazil, my answer still works ...